# Ef migration error when using default connection string on constractor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In my solution I have some database contract project that stores interfaces for contexts and some project for concrete Ef contexts, something like below:

```
public interface ISampleContext
{
    IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    IDbSet<Session> Sessions{ get; set; }
}

public class SampleContext : DbContext, ISampleContext
{
    IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    IDbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

    SampleContext() : base("name=EfDefaultConnectionString"){ ... }
    SampleContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString){ ... }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { ... }
}
```

I run the command for migration (enable, add, update, etc.) by below pattern:

```
Add-Migration
    -Name MigrationName
    -ProjectName EfProjectName
    -StartUpProjectName EfProjectName
    -ConfigurationTypeName EfProjectName
    -ConnectionStringName SomeConnectionStringName
```

But after running the commands, Ef migration fails. For solve problem, I should comment interface(s) and `: base("name=EfDefaultConnectionString")`. finally, after create migration uncomment code.
My question is why when provide connection string name, package manager console not call the `SampleContext(string connectionString)` constructor and I get below exception?

> No connection string named 'EfDefaultConnectionString' could be found in the application config file.

And second question is can I control the flow of running commands in package manager console?

last question is not exactly related to this problem, but I need now Is there any way run migration commands when "EntityFramework.dll" and "EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" "copy local" is false?

Comment: The `EfDefaultConnectionString` is for `ASPNETDB`. So you have not specified any connection string for your Code First and it uses it's default(localdb). You need to specify one in your web.config and then call it and pass it to the `base`'s constructor.

Comment: @S.Akbari The 'EfDefaultConnectionString' is sample name and in real use something like 'EfUserManagerDbConnection'. In 'add-migration' I pass '-ConnectionStringName SomeConnectionStringName' parameter, and set it in App.Config, in exception message say 'EfUserManagerDbConnection' not found. when comment  (or delete) ': base("name=EfUserManagerDbConnection")' all thing work well. So when base I thing when 'base("name=...)' available, 'SampleContext()' constractor run and when available package manager  use 'SampleContext(string connectionString)'  contractor.